# Rewrite matrix derivative with element-wise

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

Consider the following problem with a symmetric matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and vector $x \in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ and the function $f: \mathbb R^{n\times 1} \to \mathbb R$:

$$f(x) = (x\otimes x)'\left((\Sigma x\big)\otimes(\Sigma x)\right),$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the element-wise product. I want to compute the derivative with respect to $x$, which I get to be:

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (x\otimes x)'}{\partial x}\left((\Sigma x)\otimes(\Sigma x)\right)+(x\otimes x)'\frac{\partial \left((\Sigma x)\otimes(\Sigma x)\right)}{\partial x}.$$

I able to calculate the above vector of derivatives, but I am wondering if it is not possible to simplify the expression?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new vector variable
$$ y = (Ax)\circ x$$
Note that I've used a more conventional notation for the elementwise/Hadamard product. I'll also be using a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$${\rm tr}(A^TB) = A:B$$

First write the function in terms of this new variable and then find the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= y:y \cr
df
 &= 2y:dy \cr
 &= 2y:\big(x\circ(A\,dx) + (Ax)\circ dx\big) \cr
 &= 2(y\circ x):(A\,dx) + 2(y\circ(Ax)):dx \cr
 &= 2\Big(A(x\circ y) + (Ax)\circ y\Big):dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\Big(A(x\circ y) + (Ax)\circ y\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
It is helpful to know that the Hadamard and Frobenius products commute with themselves and each other
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \cr
A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
A:(B\circ C) &= (A\circ B):C \cr
}$$